# How to make a socket io connection at a specific route on the node server ? The connection should not be made user hits other enpoints on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, socket.io

I am trying to implement socket io, the basic documentation of which I have read. I am trying to implement socket io in my existing node js server. I don't want the user to be connected when he hits the other api routes, but to connect at a specific route. I think there are similar questions on this platform, I tried to refer them but I didn't understand (I am new socket-io and node).

Code:

```
 import express from 'express' ;
 import cors from 'cors'  ;
 import http from 'http' ; 
 import {Server} from 'socket.io' ; 
 import username from './routes/username.js' ; 
 import create from './routes/create.js' ;  
 import validate from './routes/validate.js' ;  
 import connection from './routes/connection.js' ; 
 import connectDb from './config/db.js' ;


 const app = express() ; 
 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000 ; 
 connectDb() ; 
 app.use(cors()) ; 
 app.use(express.json()) ; 
 app.get("/", (req,res)=> {
 res.send('<h1>Welcome to the server </h1>'); 
 })

 app.use('/api/room/create', create.router); 
 app.use('/api/room/validate', validate.router);
 app.use('/api/username', username.router ); 
 app.use('/connection',connection.router); 
 const server = http.createServer(app); 
 const io = new Server (server,{path : '/connection', serveClient : false}, {cors: 
 {origin:"http://localhost:3000"}}) ; 
 server.listen(PORT, ()=>{
 console.log(`Listening to the port on localhost: ${PORT}`) ;   
})
```

Comment: You can export ``io``, import it in your controllers and use it with ``io.emit`` or ``io.on`` depending on want to do.

Comment: Please can you elaborate it a little using code ?